# Can't link symfony app container to mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony, containers

I have a tow running containers one with **symfony app** and the other is **mysql** database server:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
99d17c328612        sbc/gestcom:1.0     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   18 hours ago        Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:4400->80/tcp                musing_moser
97dafcfb4acd        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 hours ago        Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   suspicious_brattain
```

I linked mysql container to symfony contianer like so:

```
docker container run -d -p 4400:80 --link suspicious_brattain:db sbc/gestcom:1.0
```

**suspicious_brattain**: is the name of the mysql container
**sbc/gestcom:1.0**: is the name of the image I built that contains my symfony app (with apache, php and pdo driver needed to work with mysql)
Now when I access the symfony app container to run `doctrine:database:create` I get this exception:

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
>
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
>   refused

This is `parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: my_database
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
```

Of course I gave `root` as password for mysql image when running it like so:

```
docker container run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql
```

And to be sure that the symfony container is linked to mysql container this what I get when I inspect the symfony container:

```
...
"Links": [
    "/suspicious_brattain:/musing_moser/db"
],
...
```

As you can see they are connected, however I still unable to create my database using symfony command and I get `Connection refused`!

Comment: You should check whether your MySQL service is reachable from within the container on `127.0.0.1` - if not, then there is really no connection to Symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to connect on `127.0.0.1`, but to `db`.

When linking containers, a `/etc/hosts` entry [is created in the container](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#updating-the-etchosts-file) to make configuration more convenient.

Comment: Thanks your answer worked for me but I had to do some changes on the user in mysql container `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';`